# How can I make a text appears and reappears in Javascript with getElementByClassName?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a certain text appears when you click on a text. But the getElementByClassName is not working for some reason. I don't know why?
For sure its a small detail I'm not seeing.
The goal is when you click on READ MORE, text appears and READ LESS it will disappear again.
Its 3 items wit the the same text

```
    <ul class="item-list">

        <!-- Item 1 Start-->
        <li class="item item1">
            <img src="images/chromebookpro.jpg">
            <div class="item-text">
                <h2>Google Pixelbook</h2>
                <p class="pricing">Starting at $999</p>
                <p>The first high performance Chromebook with Google Assistent built in. Features a four-in-one design offering laptop, tablet, tent, and entertainment modes, an all day battery with fast charging, a sleek aluminum body, and an optional pen. </p>
                <p class="item-specs"> Key Specs</p>
                <a href="#" onClick="change()" class="read-more">Read More</a>

                <span style="display:none" class="read-less"> More Specs.<a href="" onClick="change()" >Read Less</a></span>
                <div class="item-text-specs">
                    <div class="item-list">
                        <div class="article">12.3" Quad HD LCD</div>
                        <div class="article">Intel processor&reg;</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-list">
                        <div class="article">128/256/512 GB</div>
                        <div class="article">8/16 GB memory</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- Item 1 End-->


    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var readMore = document.getElementByClassName("read-more");
    var readLess = document.getElementByClassName('read-less');

    function change() {
        if (readLess.style.display == 'none') {
            readMore.style.display = 'none';
            readLess.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            readMore.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The function is called `getElementsByClassName`, note the S. It returns an array of the elements with that class. You may be confused because the function `getElementById` is not pluralized, since IDs should all be unique while classes can be used on multiple elements.

Comment: thanks for the error catching. but still, it isn't working. I even copy and paste the exact text getElementsByClassName for both variables

Comment: Press f12 and read the console. Otherwise if their are no errors, you'll have to explain what `isn't working`. The example answer I posted is working for me, with your html.

Comment: thank you for your advice @dustytrash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the function is called `getElementsByClassName()` - that's why it is not working, you are missing an `s` there.

Second of all this returs a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), so to select first element you'd have to use

```
var readMore = document.getElementsByClassName("read-more")[0];
```

If you need to select one element by class you can also use `document.querySelector('.class');`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

The function is called `getElementsByClassName`, note the S. It returns an array of the elements with that class.

You may be confused because the function getElementById is not pluralized, since IDs should all be unique while classes can be used on multiple elements.

```
// Changed from getElement to getElements
// function will return an array, get the first element of that array
var readMore = document.getElementsByClassName("read-more")[0];
var readLess = document.getElementsByClassName('read-less')[0];
```

I **STRONGLY** suggest looking at the console to solve errors like these in the future

Comment: Again Thank you so much @dustytrash! Yes next time I will check my console.log